# Unknown empty space between Column widgets - Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I'm trying to make it so that the body fades behind the TextField, so I decided to add a gradient on top of it, but there seems to be an empty space between the gradient and the card, and it's ruining the effect. I can't figure out where it's coming from or how to handle it.

[image: Pırt]

```
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 15,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                colors: <Color>[
                  Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
                  Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                ]),
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: Card(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                      child: TextField(
                        onTap: () => myFocusNode.requestFocus(),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Enter task',
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                        ),
                        controller: textController,
                        focusNode: myFocusNode,
                        onSubmitted: (_) {
                          submit();
                          myFocusNode.requestFocus();
                          textController.clear();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    if (!isEpoch(_selectedDate.toString()))
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                        child: FittedBox(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                DateFormat('dd/MM').format(_selectedDate),
                              ),
                              Text(timeOfDayAsHhMm(_selectedTime)),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      splashRadius: 20,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(),
                      onPressed: _dateAndTimePicker,
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      splashRadius: 20,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(),
                      onPressed: () => null,
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.image),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            CircleAvatar(
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  submit();
                  myFocusNode.requestFocus();
                  textController.clear();
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedDate = null;
                    _selectedTime = null;
                  });
                },
                child: const FittedBox(
                  child: Text(
                    'Add',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Is there some automatic padding coming from somewhere? I did use a lot of Flexibles and Boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the card add margin with zero insets

```dart
Card(
  margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
)
```